# What are the Efficient and optimized ways of making an API call in android

Tags: android

I am beginner in android, I am trying to call a [simple weather api](http://openweathermap.org/current) which returns the JSON response.

I wanted to know what are the efficient ways to make the api call and from where I can study those ways.

I have tried implementing it using Jackson:

**WebService.java** (copy paste from some link)

```
public class WebService {

    public <T> T get(String url, T object) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("x-system-code", "mobile");
        headers.set("x-server-api-password", "mobile");
        headers.set("x-server-api-key", "mobile");
        headers.set("Connection", "Close");
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity("parameters", headers);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        return (T) restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, object.getClass()).getBody();
    }

    public <T> T get(String url, T object, Map uriVariables) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Connection", "Close");
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity("parameters", headers);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        return (T) restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, object.getClass(), uriVariables).getBody();
    }


    public <T> T post(String url, Object request, T object) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("x-system-code", "mobile");
        headers.set("x-server-api-password", "mobile");
        headers.set("x-server-api-key", "mobile");
        headers.set("Connection", "Close");
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(request, headers);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        return (T) restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, object.getClass()).getBody();
    }

    public void put(String url, Object request) {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.put(url, request);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("WebService - put", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void delete(String url, Object request) {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.delete(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("WebService - delete", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}`
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebService webService=new WebService();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GetWeather getWeather=new GetWeather();
        getWeather.execute();

    }

    public class GetWeather extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, response>{

        String url;
        public GetWeather(){
            url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gurgaon&units=metric&appid=94d605bef2c15307c23f65a326d*****";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected response doInBackground(URL... params) {
            try {
                response weatherResponse= webService.get(url,new response());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(response response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            Log.i("response", response.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: unexpected end of stream on Connection{api.openweathermap.org:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=128.199.109.89 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0); nested exception is java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{api.openweathermap.org:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=128.199.109.89 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
>   01-04 07:21:51.536 21098-21137/com.example.rajatgupta.weatherapp W/System.err:     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:491)

Please tell me what am I doing wrong, or any other way to make API hit.

Comment: This question is attracting library recommendation answers (primarily opinion based)

Comment: Whatever way you choose to go "Efficient and optimized" still down to how it is coded.  Looking at your code here you are always creating new objects in every method - I'd suggest that firstly you should be employing some code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) there's heaps of good tutorials on the android developer site and all over the web.

Example usage:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    Log.d("JSON", response.toString());
                    //Do something with the data

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("JSON", error.toString());
            }
        });

VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest);
```

Comment: The question is regarding "Efficient and optimized" Api calls - I'd say pointing to a library is opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), its a pretty simple and strait forward library to help you implementing interfaces to REST APIs.